# complex numbers with 3 dimensions reopened ...

Tags: complex-numbers

can i not use two different values of complex numbers for I and J ? like √-1 for I and √-167 for J if (√-167) qualifies in the complex series

example a+Ib+Jc but I and J are different complex numbers and a,b,c constants

Comment: In this case, $j = \sqrt{167}i$. So anything you can write with $i$ and $j$ can be written with either $i$ or $j$ alone. So you can do it, but I can't think of why it would be useful.

Comment: thank you Kaynes for replying, um introducing a new complex here i mean introduction of a new plane with different geometry as compared  to i plane introduced above

Comment: As was shown above, $j \in \mathbb{C}$, so it would still be a two dimensional space, since any number in $\mathbb{C}$ is two dimensional. Look towards the quaternions for a 3D number system

Comment: introduction of a new plane in an Argand plane will shift it to three dimensions . the newly inserted plane with different geometries in accordance with the Argand plane

Comment: You're not introducing a new plane with $j$, since $j$ resides in the complex plane.

Comment: agreed , but when the complex numbers are not dealt with √-1 but new complex number is used to get the results a new plane should be added in order to get the same sequence in different problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly define new constants $I$ and $J$ and say you have a set of numbers $a+bI+cJ$ with $a,b,c$ real.  You can then define the obvious addition and subtraction of your numbers and get a group structure and three dimensional vector space over the reals.  To define multiplication you have said $I^2=-1, J^2=-167$ but you need to say what $IJ$ is and also $JI$ if the multiplication is not commutative.  As long as multiplication distributes over addition you will get a ring.  You will not be able to define division and make it work the way you are used to.  There is a theorem about what dimensions [division algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field) can have and $3$ is not one of them.

Comment: m actually trying to describe IJ multiplication as a triad which is constant ... if proved then maybe ... Ross?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a triad which is constant.  The quaternions are a four dimensional division algebra.  They have $K$ as well as $I$ and $J$ and define $I^2=J^2=K^2=-1, IJ=K, JI=-K$ for multiplication, which is not commutative.  I don't see a natural choice for $IJ$ in your system.  A lot of people have wondered about this sort of thing.  You can do some of what you want as I indicate, but probably not all.  The next question, usually not asked, is why this would be interesting.

Comment: multiplication should give a new system in different dimensions, which is consistent , if found then division algebra could be redefined